# Integral and function.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given function
$f(t) = \frac{1}{4\cdot\left(t-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$,
I have to write this function (for $ x>0 $):

$\phi (x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\;dt= ?$

I calculate the integral:
$\int\frac{1}{4\cdot\left(t-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}dt=\frac{3}{8}(t-1)^\frac{3}{2} + C $

Do I have to worry that $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+} - \left\{1\right\} $ ?

Or I can easily evaluate ${\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{4\cdot\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}dx}$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 0):

See first you have to integrate the function...
and for this you must substitute:  (t - 1) = u.
                                                     or,  dt  =  du
 and after  the integration you will get  :         (3 / 8)* u^(2 /3).  --------- (a)

as we replace (t - 1) by  U then we get the limits as:  the upper limit will be  (x - 1) and lower limit will be  (- 1).

and now we will put the values of the lower and upper limits in (a), and we will have :  (3 /8)* [ (x - 1)^(2/3)  --   1 ].

Hope the discussion will help you.best of luck.